# Private method compilation error

Tags: ios, objective-c, private

I have imported a library, but during the compilation Xcode shows an error in two .h files of this framework:

```
@interface BxAbstractDataSet (private)      

@interface BxQueueDataCommand (private)
```

after the first bracket `Expected ')'`

I thing that there is some problem with the build LLVM settings, but can't solve the issue - any help?

Comment: Did you actually copy and paste the code from your source file into your question?  Or did you retype it?  Are you sure you don't have a `#define private` somewhere?  The error you're seeing is a result of having an illegal character between the parentheses.  In my testing, `@interface AppDelegate (private)` gets no complaints, but `@interface AppDelegate (@private)` (and other variations) get the same error you're seeing.

Comment: @robmayoff the code is absolutely the same. The word private is not under define. And I have some more this syntax in project but the error is only on this two lines. Thanks for your suggestions.